# Manipulating RadioButton inside ListView on Android

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have created a custom ListView with radioButton on each its rows using Custom adapter. I want to programmatically check a radio button when its parent view (list item) is checked, and then uncheck other RadioButtons inside other ListView items. Anyone can provide me the solutions?

**UPDATE**

Here is my getView()

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout v = null;

    final Item i = items.get(position);

    EntryItem ei = (EntryItem) i;
    v = (LinearLayout) vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
    final TextView title = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
    final TextView subtitle = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);


    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    radioButton.setFocusable(false);
    radioButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    v.addView(radioButton); 

    if (title != null)
                title.setText(ei.title);
    if (subtitle != null)
                subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);


    convertView = v;
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the radio buttons, do it in `getView` method..

in the `ListView.onsetOnItemClickListener()`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
        //get the radio button and check it
                    view.findViewById(); ....   
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i access the rdBtn inside particular listView item? 
i didn't use RadioGroup, I used single RadioButton for each ListView item
BTW the RadioBUtton was created programmatically, on in XML layout

Comment: findViewById is used to access by ID (created from XML), while my RadioButton created programmatically using addView

Comment: But you can use the method, radioButton.setId()..or another alternative you can use radioButton.setTag(), and then view.findViewWithTag()

Comment: OK, this works for checking the RadioButton of the clicked item, but how to uncheck the other ones?

Comment: you can save the position of the selected item as a global variable, and in your getView(), radioButton.setChecked(selectedPosition==position);

Answer (score 4):

You can use An int variable if a single item should be selected, initialize with -1;

```
int index =-1;
```

in getView method of add a line:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout v = null;

    final Item i = items.get(position);

    EntryItem ei = (EntryItem) i;
    v = (LinearLayout) vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
    final TextView title = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
    final TextView subtitle = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);


    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    radioButton.setFocusable(false);
    radioButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    radioButton.setChecked(index==position);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {                       
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

                    }
                });
                v.addView(radioButton);
            } 
            if (title != null)
                title.setText(ei.title);
            if (subtitle != null)
                subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
        }

    convertView = v;
    return convertView;
}
```

and in OnItemClick method of listener, do:

```
index=position;
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

Comment: how can i access the rdBtn inside particular listView item?

Comment: i didn't use RadioGroup, I used single RadioButton for each ListView item

Comment: BTW the RadioBUtton was created programmatically,not in XML layout

Comment: can you paste getView method of customAdapter and xml you are inflating items.

Comment: in OnItemClickListener, what did you mean with index and what is it for after being set index=position?

Comment: its global variable to keep checked position.

Comment: Very good solution. I really liked it. Just I have to add 'radioButton.setClickable(false);' in getView()

Answer (score 1):

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Above code is from android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

It does exactly what you want to achieve. May be this can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it in the click event of list view...in setOnClickListener event, you can get the Radiobutton though view..and then you can manage it